# Why does ndimage.convolve using 3d arrays produce a 3d array instead of 2d?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I run this code:

```
x = np.random.uniform(-1,1,(3,3,3))

y = np.random.uniform(-1,1,(3,3,3))

z = ndimage.convolve(x, y, output=None, mode='reflect', cval=0.0, origin=0)

print(np.shape(z))
```

It returns (3,3,3) and I don't understand why its not producing a (3,3) array. Any explanations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to [scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html) it is multidimensional convolution, which means it convolves in every direction. You can get the middle 2D array for your purpose. Or in more general setting, remove the padded convolved elements from the third dimension:

```
z = z[...,y.shape[-1]//2:-(y.shape[-1]//2)]
```